Flow entry condition: formula field is changed
I have a record-triggered flow, with a entry condition of "formulaField IS CHANGED = true"
But i'm not sure how well this will run, as my architect believes it will not work as inteded, as a formula field is calculated real-time - and therefor might cause some issues/desync. Of what i have tested in my sandbox, it seems to work in practice - but im afraid to deploy because of the concernes of my architect. So im looking for a sencond-hand insight.

Use Case
We need to limit our contacts in Marketing Cloud, my solution is to create two fields, MarketingCloud__c (checkbox, default true) and MarketingCloudLogic__c (formula field).
A record triggered flow would then run After save, when record is created or updated.
With a Entry Condtion of MarketingCloudLogic__c IS CHANGED = true
MarketingCloud__c will then equals MarketingCloudLogic__c.
For every contact that then has MarketingCloud__c = true, will get synced to Marketing Cloud.

FYI: I have found the following help article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385534&type=1:

Formula fields do not execute in the same manner as workflow fields. They calculate and display their results in real-time whenever the field is accessed. For example, if a workflow rule uses a formula field in its criteria or formula, the formula field is evaluated only when the workflow rule criteria is checked.

If i understand this correctly, the formula field should then be calculated when the flow triggers? Which debunks the concern of my architect?

The concern from you architect is valid, but not quite for the reason you have mentioned.
You're correct that the value of the Formula Field is evaluated at runtime and no values are stored in the database. This however means that the Is Changed criteria will not behave as expected, and I suspect will either never be true OR always be true.
The way that I would typically solve for this kind of requirement would be to use a checkbox on the record, which is set to true when required. Your Flow would then utilise this as the entry criteria. If it should only operate on the record once, you'd then unselect the checkbox once all logic is complete, although in this case I would assume you'll leave it checked so that Marketing Cloud can be synced.
